# Printing 20 Rows In One Page From Data Table

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, printing

I  want  to  print  20  rows  in  one  page. I get the data from  the  data  table using for each loop.

Everything works fine if rows are less than 20. If rows are greater than 20  the code  can't  print  the  2nd  page.

Please take a look at the code below to help me find a solution.

```
        int CurrentRecord = 0;
        int RecordsPerPage = 20; // twenty items in a page
        decimal Amount = 0;
        bool StopReading = false;

   foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {

                string ItemCode = row["ItemCode"].ToString();
                g.DrawString(ItemCode, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xProductID, CurrentY);

                string PartName = row["PartName"].ToString();
                if (PartName.Length > 20)
                    PartName = PartName.Remove(20);
                g.DrawString(PartName, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xProductName, CurrentY);

                string Id = row["Identification"].ToString();
                g.DrawString(Id, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xId, CurrentY);

                string Size = row["Sizes"].ToString();
                g.DrawString(Size, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xSize, CurrentY);

                string Chasis = row["Chasis"].ToString();
                if (Chasis.Length > 6)
                    Chasis = Chasis.Remove(7);
                g.DrawString(Chasis, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xChasis, CurrentY);


                string Qty = row["Qty"].ToString();
                g.DrawString(Qty, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xQty, CurrentY);


                string Rate = row["Rate"].ToString();
                g.DrawString(String.Format("{0:0.0}", Rate), InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xPrice, CurrentY);


                //string t =Convert.ToInt32(row["Total"].ToString());

                string Total = row["Total"].ToString();

                //   FieldValue = String.Format("{0:0.00}", Amount);
                int xAmount = AmountPosition + (int)g.MeasureString("Price", InvoiceFont).Width;
                xAmount = xAmount - (int)g.MeasureString("Total", InvoiceFont).Width;
                // txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToInt32 (xAmount).ToString("N");

                g.DrawString(Total, InvoiceFont, BlackBrush, xAmount, CurrentY);


                CurrentY = CurrentY + InvoiceFontHeight;

                CurrentRecord++;

            if (CurrentRecord > RecordsPerPage)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                CurrentRecord = 0;
               // CurrentY = 20;

            }
            else
            {
                    e.HasMorePages = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `e.HasMorePages = true` in the debugger and step through your code. You keep printing after `CurrentRecord > RecordsPerPage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable at the form level:

```
int printRow = 0;
```

Before you print or in the BeingPrint event, set the value of printRow to zero.

You can't use a ForEach in this case, because you need to track your index position every time a page prints:

```
int recordsPerPage = 20;
int rowsPrinted = 0;

for (; printRow < table.Rows.Count; printRow++) {
  DataRow row = table.Rows[printRow];

  // print code

  rowsPrinted++;
  if (rowsPrinted >= recordsPerPage && printRow < table.Rows.Count - 1) {
    printRow++;
    e.HasMorePages = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also see the below link , if you have any idea please guide

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591533/after-posting-data-return-page-didt-show-completely?noredirect=1#comment80137272_46591533

Comment: @SM I can't help much on that linked question since it's about ASP.Net.  I primarily wok on desktop software.